# % Fe in a sample

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Seems so simple but is confusing me as when I take into account final weight I don't get one of the answers.

An iron ore was analysed by dissolving a $1.1324~\mathrm{g}$ sample in concentrated $\ce{HCl}$ and converting it to give $0.5394~\mathrm{g}$ of pure $\ce{Fe2O3}$. The $\mathrm{m\%}_\ce{Fe}$ in the sample is either $18.9~\%$, $25.2~\%$, $37.7~\%$ or $50.4~\%$.

**My approach:**
If I take the molar mass of iron as $55.85~\mathrm{g/mol}$ and oxygen as $15.99~\mathrm{g/mol}$. I have a $159.67~\mathrm{g/mol}$ weight for $\ce{Fe2O3}$. From this I calculated that amount of $\ce{Fe2O3}$ is$$\frac{0.5394~\mathrm{g}}{159.67~\mathrm{g/mol}}=3.378 \cdot 10^{-3}~\mathrm{mol}$$

The answer is then multiplied by ($2 \times 55.85~\mathrm{g/mol}$) giving $0.3773~\mathrm{g}$ iron but this is what is confusing.

Isn't the answer I got just for $0.5394~\mathrm{g}$ so shouldn't I take into account that I started off with $1.1324~\mathrm{g}$? If I do I get $33.32~\%$ so doesn't match an answer.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE. Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. This appears to be a [homework question](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/), please share your thoughts and attempts towards the solution. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you.

Comment: It's confusing us too. Could you provide the question and your approach in full? Your wording implies that we already know what question you're talking about.

Comment: Question from a past paper. If I take the Mass of Fe as 55.85 and O as 15.99.

Comment: Please edit in **concise** details of your attempts.

Comment: Question from a past paper. If I take the Mass of Fe as 55.85 and O as 15.99. I have a 159.67 weight for Fe2O3. From this I calculated that Mol Fe2O3 are 0.5394g*1/159.67=3.378x10-3. The answer is then multiplied by (55.85*2) giving 0.3773gFe but this is what is confusing. Isn't the answer I got just for 0.5394g so shouldn't I take into account that I started off with 1.1324g? If I do I get 33.32% so doesn't match an answer.

Comment: "Question from a last paper." **Please edit in the question in full!**

Comment: Could there be an error in the question possibilities. I got Fe at 0.377g (coincidental number?) of the 0.5324g of Fe2O3. Which turns out as 33.4% of the overall sample. I get same result as @IbrahimGeorge

Comment: Looks like part (a) from this example from [Fundamentals of Analytical Chemistry](https://books.google.com/books?id=8bIWAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA292&lpg=PA292&dq=An+iron+ore+was+analysed+by+dissolving+a+1.1324+g+sample+in+concentrated+HCl&source=bl&ots=v1thyZJNXz&sig=32YKdzWxDaA48JILONOr8YFWOkA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBWoVChMIpf3yof2WxwIVylw-Ch0k8gt-#v=onepage&q=An%20iron%20ore%20was%20analysed%20by%20dissolving%20a%201.1324%20g%20sample%20in%20concentrated%20HCl&f=false). The answer given in that case is 33.32%.

Comment: I have to admit I did come up with an answer of 33.32% but it didn't match any of the possible answerss

Comment: it is even easier than they do the calculation.$$x \cdot 1.1324~g = 70~\% \cdot  0.5394~g \Rightarrow x = 33.32~\%$$

Comment: Ok thanks, at least other people can't match the answers